# A question about antenna gain and signal property

Tags: signal, antenna, radio, gain

I have an antenna with a somewhat constant gain "X dBi (theta, phi)" in the frequency range of interest.

With this antenna we receive a radio signal with an amplitude of "Y Volt (t)".

The signal is a very short pulse which means it has a flat spectrum in the frequency range of the operation (A to B MHz).

How is it possible to derive the properties of the incoming signal to the antenna like the electric file value?

Comment: What is an 'electric file value'?? What have you tried so far?

Comment: What properties are you interested in deriving?

Comment: @PJR Thanks for your comments. I mean electric field strength that has reached the antenna. I thought maybe I can use the antenna factor and since the weight of the signal power is somewhat equal in different frequencies, use a sum on the antenna factor values for different frequencies to derive the incident electric field value.

Comment: @auspicious99 Thanks for your comment. I would like to derive any possible information about the incident signal like the electric field strength.

Answer (score 0):

> properties of the incoming signal to the antenna

You can't.

All you observe is the electric signal; there's infinitely many possible electromagnetic waves that can lead to an identical signal at the antenna output.

Think about it: Say your wave comes in from the main lobe direction and has an amplitude of 1 V.

Now imagine a wave with *twice* the power arrives from an angle with a gain of -3dB – the resulting signal will be identical.

So, you can't.

Comment: Thanks. Now let's assume we know the specifications of the signal that we're looking for. Let's assume that we can remove the unwanted signals that has been received by the antenna. Is it make any difference in order to be able to derive the specification of the incoming signal especially the power of the signal?

Answer (score 0):

All you can state - assuming an ideal isotropic antenna (Marcus Müller pointed out, that in reality it is rarely the case) - what the incoming power was. Based on my somewhat limited understanding on electromagnetic waves, the energy of the traveling waves are oscillating between the electric and magnetic fields.